# Setting up time triggers on video player

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libvlc

**Background**:

I have a some text that I want to display in a textbox whenever the video is playing in a certain interval, say `(00:02:00-00:04:00 "Hello there")`.

These textbox should only be displayed whenever the video is playing in the particular interval. If I rewind, or skip the video to a different time, the textbox should be generated/destroyed depending whether the current time falls within the interval or not.

I have searched the documentation for ffplay and vlc for implementing this functionality.

**What I have tried**:

ffplay: my strategy would be to keep polling the current time of the video which ffplay dumps in STDERR and check if the current time falls within the interval.

LibVLC:
LibVLC supports asynchronous events, but not the kind which would depend on the time at which video is playing.

**My question**:

1.Is it advisable to keep polling the current video time or setup callbacks/trigger functions?

2.Is it possible to get the current playing time of the video as a variable and create callback functions accordingly?

**NOTE:** I am aware that subtitles do the same thing, however I want the text to be in a different window. The textbox should be decoupled from the video player I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are interested in is the current video time or position, polling is perfectly fine.  LibVLC does implement callbacks for `Media Player Position Changed` and `Media Player Time Changed` but for something that is performed very regularly (like querying the time every second), there isn't a lot of value to handling it as an async event.

Set up a timer to query every second (or half second depending on what kind of precision you want) and call:

```
libvlc_time_t current = libvlc_media_player_get_time(my_player);
```

Note, the result is in milliseconds.  And you will obviously have to keep a reference to your `my_player` around but I assume you will have done that.  Also note, in my experience, the time reported by `libvlc_media_player_get_time` might not always be very precise.  But for playback it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `subtitle` file e.g.
a file with your video name but ending in `.srt`

Myvideo.srt containing:

```
1
00:02:00,001 --> 00:04:00,001
Hello There!
```

Vlc should pick it up automatically.

ffplay may need to be told about it.

`ffplay -ss 00:01:55.00 -i Myvideo.mp4 -vf subtitles="./Myvideo.srt`
`

Answer (score 0):

I subscribe to the PositionChanged event of an LibVLCSharp.WinForms.VideoView.MediaPlayer Instance in my player form.

First, I have an object defined as follows:

```
public class VidMark
{
    public long Beg { get; set; } //Number of milliseconds of the beginning 
    public long End { get; set; } //Number of milliseconds of the end
    public string Desc { get; set; } //Text to display
    public int Rank { get; set; } = 0; //A rank value for how user likes it
}
```

I keep a list of these marks for each video. I show them on my timeline of the video with a colored mark.
While the video is playing and the PositionChanged event occurs, I check whether the current time falls within any of these marks. If so, I display the description and rank to the user.

```
//longMS = milliseconds into video derived from e.Position of the event
foreach (VidMark VM in _CurrentVidMarks)
{
    if (VM.Beg <= longMS && longMS < VM.End)
    {
        //In a VidMark, so show it in the app
        SetCurrentVidMarkAndControls(VM);
        break;
    }
}
```